# Windows Phone 8: Using a remote uri for MediaHistoryItem ImageSource

Tags: windows-phone, background-agents, background-audio

Every sample I've seen for updating the historyitem in a Windows Phone 8 Media Hub app shows using a local image/uri for displaying the background of the item.

However, I am streaming the file, and I have a remote URI for that song cover, but I cannot seem to use this uri for the history item.

I attempted to download the image to localstorage, but this appears to not always work, and crashes the background agent.

not to mention the fact that I have to do this asynchronously, and needs to support downloading it from the background agent in case the user is not running the app when the track changes...

am I attempting to do something that isn't supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No what you are attempting is supported. It is possible to download images in background agents and then use them for the history items.

Comment: thank you indeed this is supported, but I thinks it's unfortunate that it doesn't allow you to use a remote uri natively, but rather I have to download it manually. that being said the crash was due to incorrectly using the NotifyComplete(), fixing that resolved the crash, thanks for your input!